# How to create kubernetes job spec to run perl script?

Tags: kubernetes

How to create kubernetes job configuration spec to run perl script ? once the script completes execution , job created pod should go to completion .

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It should be the same as any other Job spec: create a Docker image containing the script, push it to a registry, and name that image as the `image:` field in the Job.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 2):

As we can find in the [Kubernetes Jobs documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) - when a specified number of successful completions is reached, the Job is complete:

> A Job creates one or more Pods and will continue to retry execution of the Pods until a specified number of them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the Job tracks the successful completions. When a specified number of successful completions is reached, the task (ie, Job) is complete.

I guess you would like to use a [non-parallel Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs):

> - normally, only one Pod is started, unless the Pod fails.
> - the Job is complete as soon as its Pod terminates successfully.

A container in a Pod may fail for a number of reasons, such as because the process in it (e.g a perl script) exited with a non-zero exit code. This will happen, for example, when the perl script fails:
**NOTE:** I typed `prin` instead of `print`.

```
$ cat test-perl.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

prin("Hello World\n");

$ ./test-perl.pl
Undefined subroutine &main::prin called at ./test-perl.pl line 5.

$ echo $?
255   ### non-zero exit code
```

I've created an example to illustrate how you can create a Job that runs a perl script and completes successfully.

---

First, I created a simple perl script:

```
$ cat perl-script.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @i = (1..9);

for(@i){
print("$_: Hello, World!\n");

$ ./perl-script.pl
1: Hello, World!
2: Hello, World!
3: Hello, World!
4: Hello, World!
5: Hello, World!
6: Hello, World!
7: Hello, World!
8: Hello, World!
9: Hello, World!

$ echo $?
0
```

Then I created a Docker image with the above script and pushed it to my [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/) repository:
**NOTE:** I used the [perl](https://hub.docker.com/_/perl) image.

```
$ ls
Dockerfile  perl-script.pl

$ cat Dockerfile
FROM perl:5.20
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
CMD [ "perl", "./perl-script.pl" ]

$ docker build . --tag mattjcontainerregistry/perl-script
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
...
Successfully tagged mattjcontainerregistry/perl-script:latest

$ docker push mattjcontainerregistry/perl-script:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/mattjcontainerregistry/perl-script]
...
latest: digest: sha256:2f8789af7f61cfb021337810963a9a19f133d78e9ad77159fbc1d425cfb1d7db size: 3237
```

Finally, I created a `perl-script` Job which runs the perl script I created earlier:

```
$ cat perl-job.yml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: perl-script
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: perl-script
        image: mattjcontainerregistry/perl-script:latest
      restartPolicy: Never

$ kubectl apply -f perl-job.yml
job.batch/perl-script created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
perl-script-gspzz   0/1     Completed   0          10s

$ kubectl get job
NAME          COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
perl-script   1/1           1s         18s

$ kubectl logs -f perl-script-gspzz
1: Hello, World!
2: Hello, World!
3: Hello, World!
4: Hello, World!
5: Hello, World!
6: Hello, World!
7: Hello, World!
8: Hello, World!
9: Hello, World!
```

As you can see, the `perl-script` Job is complete, so it works as expected.